# Google isn't able to search my website

Tags: seo, google-search

I have recently started a new website namely webivorous.tk(WordPress CMS) and google is not able to search/index my website.I searched google for my website many times but it doesn't come up with results.Please Help.Thanks

Comment: Have you tried submitting your site to Google via Webmaster tools? This is likely not a WordPress issue.

Answer (score 1):

You may have disabled indexing, ensure you have 'Discourage search engines from indexing this site' unchecked under Settings -> Reading